# Decomposition of a covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics, normal-distribution, covariance

The covariance matrix can be written as $$\Sigma = AA^{T}$$.

My lecturer told me we can decompose the empirical covariance matrix as

$$\widehat{\Sigma} = \Sigma + \Sigma^{1/2} T \Sigma^{1/2}$$

where $$T_{ij} \sim N(0,2/n) \hspace{1cm} i=j$$

and $$T_{ij} \sim N(0,1/n) \hspace{1cm} i \neq j$$

Do you know why this decomposition is possible ?

Comment: Do you know about the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)?

Comment: Yes of course , but its a decomposition in form of $\Sigma = UVD^{T} $

Comment: Instead of guessing $\Sigma$s decomposition, guess $A$s.

Comment: Hmmm so A can be decomposed like this ?

Comment: but $$\Gamma$$ is not a diagonal matrix ...  traditionally (regarding SVD) the matrix V is one.

Comment: but why we can decompose A in terms of $\Sigma$ ? and why are the entries of $T$ normally distributed ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition All real or complex matrices can be decomposed like this. I don't know what matrix $\Gamma$ is

Comment: sorry - meant T instead of $\Gamma$

Comment: just dont know why T is normally distributed .. ??

Comment: Sums of equidistributed random variables will approach a normal distribution. I think it could have something to do with that.